# Is it possible render two different buffers with different indices starting point in the same call in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have these two objects, defined like so:
Object 1:

```
vertices = {...}
indices = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...}
```

And Object 2:

```
vertices = {...}
indices = {1, 2, ...}
```

Where vertices is a vector of floats that gets pushed to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and indices is a vector of unsigned that gets pushed to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

These objects do not have transformations that need to be applied to them and are relatively static but can be modified by the user.

I didn't want to create a single object that contains all the vertices of the two objects because I wanted the modifications to these objects to be as fast as possible, so the smaller the object the faster it is to rebuild the mesh. I know that two draw calls on two small objects are slower than one draw call on a single, even if the object is a bit bigger, so I wanted to batch them together.

My problem is that I can push or remove vertices from the buffer with `glBufferSubData`, but for the indices, I would need to loop through every value of the second object and offset it to account for the indices of the first object, so it would end up being slower probably.

The objects can have very different sizes, so I don't think fixed offset could be a viable solution either.

Is it possible to tell OpenGL that the indices of the first object are referred to the vertices of the first object and the indices of the second object are referred to the vertices of the second object? In this case, I would be able to modify only a part of the buffer object, without the need to offset the indices for each object every time.

Answer (score 1):

The `baseVertex` parameter of the [various `BaseVertex` rendering commands](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Base_Index) are meant to do essentially what you're asking for. The `baseVertex` parameter is an integer that gets added to each *index* in the rendering command before fetching that any vertex attributes from the vertex buffers.

Let's say this is your index buffer:

```
0 1 2 1 3 2 0 1 2 1 3 2
|  Mesh 0  |  Mesh 1  |
```

If mesh 0 has 4 vertices, then you pass 4 as the `baseVertex` to `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` or a similar command. This effectively makes the indices in mesh 1 `4 5 6 5 7 6`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a question, if I understood correctly, this doesn't enable me to render two objects in one draw call but it enables me to share the same buffer between two objects, and draw them separately, right? So If I was to modify the values of one object I still would have to recreate the entire buffer?

Comment: @Fabrizio: You no longer have to "loop through every value of the second object and offset it to account for the indices of the first object". As for copying and so forth, that's really a matter of what allocation strategies you want to employ.